# How to make new connection (reconnect after send a few emails) in php mailer?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, phpmailer, command-line-arguments

this is my code. 
i can't make this mailer reconnect after send a few emails.
like i want them to reconnect after send 3 emails

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$get=file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$j=explode("\r\n",$get);
foreach($j as $email) {

print "\n\t";
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                       // telling the class to use SMTP

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                  
// 0 = no output, 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only.
$reconnect = 3;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                // enable SMTP authentication 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";              // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "smtp-relay.gmail.com";        // sets Gmail as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 587;                     // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL 
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->Username = "admin@example.com";  // Gmail username
$mail->Password = "password";      // Gmail password
$mail->SetFrom ('admin@example.com', 'No Reply');
$mail->SetLanguage('de', 'language/');
$mail->Priority = 1;
$mail->Encoding = '7bit';
$mail->CharSet = 'windows-1250';
$mail->Subject = 'crazy test';
$mail->ContentType = 'text/html'; 
//$mail->AddEmbeddedImage ("logo.jpg", "okgambar");
$mail->IsHTML();

$mail->Body = file_get_contents('new-2.txt');

$nq=0;
$mail->AddAddress ($email, 'ImakoChan');     
// you may also use this format $mail->AddAddress ($recipient);

if(!$mail->Send()) 
{
        echo $error_message = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else 
{
        echo $error_message = "Successfully sent!";
}
if(empty($reconnect)){
$reconnect=6;
}

if($reconnect==$nq){
$mail->SmtpClose();echo "<p><b>--------------- SMTP CLOSED AND ATTEMPTS TO RECONNECT NEW CONNECTION SESSION --------------- </b></p>";$nq=0;
}
$nq=$nq+1;
                flush(); 

}
?>
```

i want this mailer reconnect after send after send a few emails
But the results still send without reconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-positioning your code and check for count like this should do the trick:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$get = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$j = explode("\r\n", $get);
$count = 0; //init count here and default to 0
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // init mail here before loop
foreach ($j as $email) {

    if ($count > 2) { // once count has reached 3 or more close and reopen
        $mail->SmtpClose();

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $count = 0;//reset count
    }


    print "\n\t";


    $mail->IsSMTP();                       // telling the class to use SMTP

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    // 0 = no output, 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only.
    $reconnect = 3;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                // enable SMTP authentication 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";              // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host = "smtp-relay.gmail.com";        // sets Gmail as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 587;                     // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL 
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->Username = "admin@example.com";  // Gmail username
    $mail->Password = "password";      // Gmail password
    $mail->SetFrom('admin@example.com', 'No Reply');
    $mail->SetLanguage('de', 'language/');
    $mail->Priority = 1;
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';
    $mail->CharSet = 'windows-1250';
    $mail->Subject = 'crazy test';
    $mail->ContentType = 'text/html';
    //$mail->AddEmbeddedImage ("logo.jpg", "okgambar");
    $mail->IsHTML();

    $mail->Body = file_get_contents('new-2.txt');

    $nq = 0;
    $mail->AddAddress($email, 'ImakoChan');
    // you may also use this format $mail->AddAddress ($recipient);

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo $error_message = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo $error_message = "Successfully sent!";
    }
    $count++;
}

?>
```

Comment: This will work, but you don't actually have to recreate the PHPMailer object in its entirety. It's more efficient to create one instance and set everything that doesn't change before your sending loop, then only set the things that are different each time in the loop. Calling `SmtpClose()` is enough to make it close the connection, and it will automatically reopen it the next time you call `send()`. Take a look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer for an example.

Comment: ops, i have new probelm with this. before the smtp closed, mailer send 2emails together. not one by one. why?